# Turning a Queue into a Priority Queue

Tags: java, priority-queue

In the CarWash program that I have right now there is currently a normal queue that I would like to change into a priority queue. My goal is to take one of the basic server characteristics and use that for  priority but I am lost on how to do that. In previous attempts I have tried to change the normal queue into a priority queue and have ran into issues on how I am supposed to base it off a server characteristic.

```
public class CarWash {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter wash time: ");
        int WASHTIME = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter arrival probability: ");
        double ARRIVALPROB = kb.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("enter time for simulation: ");
        int TOTALTIME = kb.nextInt();
        carWashSimulate(WASHTIME, ARRIVALPROB, TOTALTIME);
    }

    public static void carWashSimulate(int washTime, double arrivalProb, int totalTime) { //simulates the car wash
        Queue<Integer> arrivalTimes = new LinkedList<Integer>( );  
        
        int next;
        ClientGenerator arrival = new ClientGenerator(arrivalProb);
        Server machine = new Server(washTime);
        ExpressServer newM = new ExpressServer(washTime);
        Averager waitTimes = new Averager( );
        Averager lostCustomer = new Averager();
        int currentSecond;

        // Write the parameters to System.out.
        System.out.println("Seconds to wash one car: " + washTime);
        System.out.print("Probability of customer arrival during a second: ");
        System.out.println(arrivalProb);
        System.out.println("Total simulation seconds: " + totalTime); 

        // Check the precondition:
        if (washTime <= 0 || arrivalProb < 0 || arrivalProb > 1 || totalTime < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Values out of range"); 

        for (currentSecond = 0; currentSecond < totalTime; currentSecond++) { 
            // Simulate the passage of one second of time
            // Check whether a new customer has arrived.
            if (arrival.query( )){
                System.out.println("Customer arrived at " + currentSecond);
                if(arrivalTimes.size() <= 8){
                    arrivalTimes.add(currentSecond);
                }
            else{
                System.out.println("They left, line was too long");
                lostCustomer.addNumber(1);
            }

            // Check whether we can start washing another car.
            if ((!machine.isBusy( ))  &&  (!arrivalTimes.isEmpty( )))
            {
                next = arrivalTimes.remove( );
                waitTimes.addNumber(currentSecond - next);
                machine.start( );
                System.out.println("Server started at " + currentSecond + " serving customer " + next);
            }
            

            // Subtract one second from the remaining time in the current wash cycle.
            machine.reduceRemainingTime( );
        } // end of for loop

        // Write the summary information about the simulation.
        System.out.println("Customers served: " + waitTimes.howManyNumbers( )); 
        if (waitTimes.howManyNumbers( ) > 0)
            System.out.println("Average wait for customers served: " + waitTimes.average( ) + " sec");
            System.out.println("The number of customers lost was " + lostCustomer);
        } 
    }
}
```

Client Generator Class:

```
public class ClientGenerator { 
private double probability; 
// The approximate probability of query( ) returning true. 
public ClientGenerator(double p) { 
    if ((p < 0) || (1 < p)) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal p: " + p); 
    probability = p; 
} 

public void adjust(double a) {
    if(a > 0 && a+probability < 1) {
        probability = probability + a;
    } else if (a < 0 && probability + a > 0) {
        probability = probability + a;
    }
}

public double getProbability() {
    return probability;
   }
    
public boolean query( ) { 
    return (Math.random( ) < probability); 
} 


}
```

Server Class:

```
public class Server { 
private int secondsForService; // Seconds for a single wash 
private int timeLeft; // Seconds until this Server is no longer busy 
public Server(int s) { 
secondsForService = s; 
timeLeft =0; 
} 
public boolean isBusy( ) { 
    return (timeLeft > 0); 
} 
public void reduceRemainingTime( ) { 
    if (timeLeft > 0) timeLeft--; 
} 
public void start( ) { 
    if (timeLeft > 0) 
        throw new IllegalStateException("Server is already busy."); 
    timeLeft = secondsForService;
  } 
}
```

Averager class:

```
public class Averager
    {
       private int count;  // How many numbers have been given to this averager
       private double sum; // Sum of all the numbers given to this averager                  
       
   public Averager( )
   {
       count =0;
       sum = 0;
   }
   
   public void addNumber(double value)
   {
      if (count == Integer.MAX_VALUE)
         throw new IllegalStateException("Too many numbers");
      count++;
      sum += value;
   }
 
   public double average( )
   {
      if (count == 0)
         return Double.NaN;
      else
         return sum/count;
   } 

   public int howManyNumbers( )
   {
      return count;
   }
}
```

Comment: I see only one Queue in the code presented, and it contains only `Integer` arrival times.  Are these what you want to place in a PriorityQueue?  If so, then how are those times associated with servers?  You need such an association if you are going to use server characteristics to set priority.

Comment: More generally, I'm not sure I understand the problem.  Are you asking how to configure a `java.util.PriorityQueue` for different priority rules?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I added the rest of my classes for better understand of what I am trying to do. Right now my goal is to implement some way of randomly assigning a value that represents the type of car, which will then prioritize the luxury car before the other cars. My problem is I can't figure out how to implement this into my code because my knowledge is limited on how to create the priority queues.

Comment: Well, I don't know ... is [that](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/priority_queue.htm) of any help perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be about how to configure the priority rules employed by a [`java.util.PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).  That's relatively straightforward.  Depending on which constructor you use to instantiate one, `PriorityQueue` relies either on the natural order of its elements (see [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html)) or on the order defined by a specified [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html).  Whenever such a queue contains any elements, its head is the least with respect to the operative ordering, or among the least if there are multiple elements such that no other element is less.

In comments you clarified

> my goal is to implement some way of randomly assigning a value that represents the type of car, which will then prioritize the luxury car before the other cars.

Note well that `PriorityQueue` uses the properties of the enqueued objects to establish their relative order.  Right now you are enqueuing integer arrival times, which don't confer an ability to distinguish between classes of car.  If you want to carry more information about each vehicle that arrives then you would probably want to create a new class for that, maybe something like this:

```
class ClientArrival {
    enum Category { NORMAL, LUXURY }

    Category category;
    int arrivalTime;

    // ...
}
```

You would then be able to create one or more implementations of `Comparator<ClientArrival>` to use to define the priority rule for a `PriorityQueue<ClientArrival>`.  For example,

```
class LuxuryFirstComparator implements Comparator<ClientArrival> {
    int compare(ClientArrival o1, ClientArrival o2) {
        if (o1.getCategory() == o2.getCategory()) {
            // ... order based on arrival time ...
        } else if (o1.getCategory() == ClientArrival.Category.LUXURY) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

One might set up a `PriorityQueue<ClientArrival>` using that to determine priority via

```
Queue<ClientArrival> arrivals = new PriorityQueue<>(new LuxuryFirstComparator());
```